# Rename file containing spaces and punctuation marks

Tags: shell, filenames

Someone in our Global Linux 3.0.31-0.9 server has put a file with several spaces, parenthesis, question mark and a colon in its name.

And I am at my wit's end to rename or remove it!

Sample of the file name and commands I tried to remove/rename the file to "gibberish" is attached [here](https://jumpshare.com/b/OlTT2rlRls1R5xUsiBTQ).

My `ls` output:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root       11306 May  2 03:25 who suggesting to assign this issue to the group which is responsible for the application StreamServe. (Probably it is operated by Linq????:q
-rw-------  1 root   root       15797 Jun 12 12:59 .viminfo
-rw-------  1 root   root        1200 Jun 12 13:00 .lesshst
drwxrwxrwx 32 root   root        4096 Jun 13 00:00 .snapshot
-rw-------  1 root   root       32976 Jun 13 14:05 .bash_history
```

Comment: sorry for the broken link...
it is again [link](http://jmp.sh/cf1FL15)

Comment: Just quote the filename. `rm 'some file (with spaces)'`

Comment: @jordanm did try that, did not work. But I have now 2 solution & am a bit wiser. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enclosing the filename in question in quotes is probably the easiest way to remove or rename it.  First create a test file:

```
rm "   -myfile(1):ok?"
```

If a file simply begins with a hyphen, use "--" to tell the command that no more options exist and that the leading hyphen is a command argument:

```
rm -- -myfile
```

In cases where your file name has unprintable characters, you can use remove it with `find` having determined its inode number:

```
find . -iname "*myfile*" -exec ls -i {} +
```

9225180 ./   -myfile(1):ok?

```
find . -inum 9225180 -exec rm -i {} +
```

remove ./   -myfile(1):ok??

Adding the `-i` (interactive) response to commands like `rm` allows you to confirm that you are operating on the entity you want first.

Comment: Thanks !!  @JRFerguson
find and -inum worked like a charm...

[results](http://jmp.sh/8wtTMtS)

Alas ! no reputations to upvote yet !

Comment: @RustyNails even without reputation you can still accept JRFerguson's answer; that will give you reputation too.

Answer (score 3):

The easy way to act on a file with a difficult-to-type name is to use completion. In this case, since the first few characters of the name are easy to type, type them, and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

```
$ mv whoTab found.txt
```

If you were unable to determine the first character, you could press <kbd>Tab</kbd> after `./`, to cycle through all the file names in the current directory.

The shell's completion command will generate a quoted string, using `'` or `\` or however it's programmed.

Alternatively, you can make this quoted string yourself. Inside single quotes, all characters are interpreted normally, except a single quote itself. So if the file name doesn't contain any single quote, paste it between single quotes — but you need to have the actual file name (as printed by `ls --show-control-chars`), not the file name with some nonprintable characters substituted. If there is a single quote in the file name, replace it by `'\''` (single quote, backslash, single quote, single quote). For example, for a file called `it's`, you can use `'it'\''s'`.

Alternatively, you can craft a wildcard pattern that only matches this file. For example, in this case:

```
$ ls -d w*
who suggesting to assign this issue to the group which is responsible for the application StreamServe. (Probably it is operated by Linq????:q
wibble
```

In my example, there are two matching files, so the wildcard isn't good enough. Adding a character cuts it.

```
$ ls -d wh*
who suggesting to assign this issue to the group which is responsible for the application StreamServe. (Probably it is operated by Linq????:q
mv who* found.txt
```

If the first character isn't printable, you can pick another pattern matching a different part of the name. You can use a pattern like `[!#-z]*` or `[!0-9A-Z_a-z]*` or `[![:alnum:]]*` which exclude characters commonly used at the beginning of a file name.

If the file name begins with `-` (ASCII dash or hyphen), it may be interpreted as an option. Use `./-wibble` to make avoid this.

Comment: Yes that could also have worked.