# Can't remove files with these names

Tags: bash

I was writing a file management program in C and accidentally created two files that I can't delete.

File 1:
`''$'\n'`

File 2: `'b.txt'$'\n'`

Typing `rm` and hitting `tab` twice doesn't even display them.

How do I delete them?

Edit:

Output of `ls -la`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 0 Feb 7 04:12 ''$'\n'
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 0 Feb 7 00:48 'b.txt'$'\n'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the output of `ls -la` on the relevant directory. Are the single quotes part of the file name?

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/451810/deleting-files-using-pattern-matching-for-files-containing-spaces-and-asterisks for detailed answer. if there isn't too many files in directory you can use `rm -i` (see man page)

Comment: @terdon Post edited. Don't believe they're part of the file name.

Comment: @Archemar There are quite a few files, so I'd rather avoid deleting the entire directory if possible. Though I suppose I could copy all other files out before doing so. I wouldn't want to do that every single time I accidentally create a file like this, though.

Comment: Finding their inode with `ls -i` and using `find` would be an option.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk This worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

That should probably be `'b.txt'$'\n'` in the latter, with the final single quote.

That looks like the output of GNU ls with the quoting style `shell-escape`. Recent versions of GNU ls use some such quoting by default.
You can verify it's that by running `ls -l --quoting-style=shell-escape` to see if that gives the same output. As the name says, the output is quoted like the shell does it, so it can be used as input to the shell. Hence, it should be possible to remove either or both files by just copypasting the quoted/escaped output from `ls` to Bash:

```
ls -l ''$'\n' 'b.txt'$'\n
```

and then of course `rm ...` after you verify you got the right files.

For what it's worth, the first filename is just a lone newline (for some reason the escaping adds the leading empty `''`), the second is `b.txt` and a newline at the end.

Comment: Using `find` on their inode number seemed to show them as `?` and `b.txt?`, so I assume that `?` is the newline?

Comment: @Anthony the man page for GNU find says that for `-print` (the default action), the filename is quoted "in the same way as for GNU ls" (when printed to a terminal), so perhaps it indeed changes nonprintable characters to `?`s. That's what `ls` does too, with other quoting style settings.

Answer (score 0):

Enter "rm *filename as displayed by ls*" to remove files, e.g.

```
rm ''$'\n'
```

Background:

1. Your filenames got a newline character appended (or, in case of `''$'\n'`, even consist only of a single newline character)
2. Enter `ls -N` to get a different (the traditional) view
3. Regarding `$'\n'`, which represents the newline character, see "ANSI-C Quoting" (http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)
4. Regarding different output formats of ls, see "GNU Coreutils - Quoting File names" (https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/quotes.html), or man page ls(1) (`man 1 ls`) - look for "quoting"
5. It seems, shell tab completion cannot handle filenames containing a newline character properly, and especially `''$'\n'`
6. Filenames starting with a new line character are treated specially by `ls` by prepending two single quotes - might be a bug

Comment: Bash at least can tab-complete filenames with newlines just fine, though with the filename only containing the newline, it's hard to do since you don't have anything to start the tab-completion. (Unless it's the only file in the directory.) The bash-completion scripts, on the other hand, are probably totally incapable of dealing with newlines.